# Rotating large images in python (85000x85000x3)

Tags: python, image, opencv, scipy, rotation

Does anyone know of a python library that can be used to rotate very large images? I need to ensure that the images use the same colors and that there is no interpolation, that is I have to use a nearest neighbor rotation.

The image is in `tiff` format. I'm using a NVIDIA DGX to process it, this server holds 512 GB of system memory.

***OPENCV***

I tried using opencv:

```
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w/2,h/2),angle,1)
im_rgb_rot = cv2.warpAffine(im_rgb,M,(w,h),flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

And it seems like after the rotation `im_rgb_rot` becomes a blank image consisting of all zeros.

***SCIPY***

Also, I tried using `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate` and `scipy.misc.imrotate` and on a small test image but it seems like the rotation does not give me straight edges as seen below. I should note that opencv gives straight edges.

[image]

The code for this is:

```
scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(im_test, 40, reshape=False, mode='nearest')
```

***PIL***

Finally, I cannot use PIL as it does not support such large images.

Comment: That's 14.5 terrabytes uncompressed. You haven't come anywhere near providing enough information. For starters, you need to explain how these things are stored and what computing resources you have to do the job.

Comment: Sorry, I will update the post with it, but these are `tiff` images. There are a range of sizes and the largest size is 85000x85000x3, I have not worked with this size yet. But since `tiff` images are 3 bytes a pixel, I believe the image will be around 50-65GB of data. I'm using a NVIDIA DGX which has 512GB of system memory.

Comment: I'm sorry, don't know where I got my by math. 22Gb ought to be doable on this  machine, but you'll definitely need a thoroughly 64-bit library. Have you looked at ImageMagick? Their docs have a section on "massive images" http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#massive .  You can experiment with the command line tool, but I believe there's a Python API (I know there's one for Ruby). A part of this may be setting your OS to allow allocations this big.  You didn't mention the OS.

Answer (score 1):

[pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips) can process large images quickly using only a little memory.

To rotate a large image by 20 degrees you might write:

```
import pyvips

x = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("M7_KM-1.tif")
x = x.rotate(20, interpolate=pyvips.Interpolate.new("nearest"))
x.write_to_file("x.tif", compression="jpeg", tile=True)
```

Where `M7_KM-1.tif` is a 65k x 65k pixel tiled JPG-compressed TIFF image. On my desktop PC (four core, 8 thread i7 plus an SSD) I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e python3 rot.py 
1066960:54.06
```

So a peak of just over 1gb of memory and 57s of elapsed real time.

Comment: pyvips has never disappointed me. Kudos to John